# Resize view when another view is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, iad, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `tableView` and a `iAd banner` beneath the `tableView`.

**Goal**

I'm trying to make the `tableViews` height get larger  when the `banner` is unable to receive ads. And when it can get ads, the `tableViews` height should shrink. (I would like to have animation if possible.)

**Problem**

When I run the app the `banner` is hidden initially (see code below), and the 
`tableViews` height is as if there's a `banner`. Meaning it has the space on the bottom. Then when the `banner` appears, the `tableViews` height becomes even smaller and it has the space for 2 `banners`.

(If this isn't clear please let me know and I'll post an image.)

Here's the constraints:

UITableView:
[image]

iAd Banner:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.bottomAddView?.hidden = false
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.bottomAddView?.hidden = true
}
```

**Update**

I tried adding a `height constraint` to the `ad banner`, and when I run the app, I get the following error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<myAPp.MainViewController 0x7f9bd1d213b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bottomAddView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011048ac65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110123bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011048a8a9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010fcb9b53 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001103d2d50 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000110d0752b -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000110b5f718 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000110b5fd08 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000110b5ff79 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000110b9001b -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 44
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000110b90565 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 216
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000110b90664 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 92
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000110b91448 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 523
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000110b91f0e -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000110cdc715 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000110aafa2b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000011275dec2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001127526d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112752546 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00000001126be886 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    20  QuartzCore                          0x00000001126bfa3a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000110a2da2d -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 44
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000110a2e6f1 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2648
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000110a2d0d5 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    24  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011771d5e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001103be41c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001103b4165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001103b3947 __CFRunLoopRun + 887
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001103b3366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000110a2cb42 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000110a2f900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    31  myApp                             0x000000010f9b3207 main + 135
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112f82145 start + 1
    33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a height constraint to your iAd banner and make it's outlet in your ViewController. And change your functions:

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.bottomAddView?.hidden = false
    self.yourBannerHeightConstraint.constant = someValue
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.bottomAddView?.hidden = true
    self.yourBannerHeightConstraint.constant = 0
}
```

And that's it!

Comment: But then I will have to change it when the orientation changes. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe it is, but I don't know(. Also if you will go this way don't forget to make the same things with your banner's top spacing constraint. Otherwise you'll have some blank area.

Comment: That's without code. Only the height constraint in storyboard

Comment: Is `bottomAddView` your adView? If yes, try to connect the height constraint to outlet, maybe it causes the exception.

Comment: One more thing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key#answer-8087739